# What is the meaning of "afterburne"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I just wonder and I'm asking this here, because I couldn't find any closer match to the very interesting word "afterburne" . Well, I know it written incorrectly, but I've heard this one, with "Jemand afteburne zu ...".
Please let me know how to write this word correctly if you could recognize this one.

Thanks

Can't remember properly,

But sounds like:

"aftebune" or "aftbune"?
One thing I know is that there were both "bune" && "~aft", so I know the word I write isn't correct, but I'm sure there were two aforementioned words

Comment: Welcome to GL&U! Is there perhaps anything more to the phrase you can remember or how it was used? Or could you try to write it out phonetically instead of in pseudo-German? It might help.

Comment: This is still not enough. Where did you get that? What was the context? Do you know where the person who said that lives or comes from? And if you're familiar with IPA, please provide your best guess regarding pronunciation. As you written the word it sounds English to me, thus it could be a borrowed word.

Comment: The headline says afte**r**bu**r**ne, not aftebune, so which is it? Nachbrennen is a common word in engineering (Nachbrenner/Afterburner). I think a Turbolader does so.

Comment: As a noun, it could also relate to post sun bathing cooling lotion - Afterburn/Aftersun.

Comment: @metal_fan You'll likely not have read the short discussion between Takkat and me to his already deleted answer. We're going to close that question if you can't provide any more concrete details which makes it possible to make an funded research on that issue. We don't appreciate quizzes and in its current state this question is just a riddle.

Comment: @Em1: Maybe it is just aft bun or afbu, abu - like Abu Graib. Or AU like AskUbuntu? After ull, we don't know. ;)

Comment: @Em1 I've read this, and wanna thank you both for this. I really couldn't get additional info, so that this makes it easier to understand. Duh, it sucks, I know. The answer was : Auf der Buhne which sounds closely to afte bune :)

Comment: @userunknown this is: Auf Der Buhne

Comment: @metal_fan: You mean backstage? Auf der Bühne - ''Bühne'' mit Umlaut und ''der'' klein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeing your nick "metal_fan", I wonder if maybe you mean something like "Auf der Bühne" (on stage)?
"Jemandem auf der Bühne zu(jubeln/hören/winken)" would fit.

But Ern1 has a point: This is more a riddle than a question...

Comment: Who is Ern1? ;)

Comment: Em12 would be right. Well - better, fränkischer Hausflur mit 3 Buchstaben (plus 1 Ziffer).

Comment: This is a perfect example where some form of phonetic notation would have helped a lot. Note to myself: include missing umlauts in future guessing games.